# Arabic language not working in VBA

Tags: vba, arabic

So I have some simple code. It loops through a given folder, opens any xlsx files, then loops through the sheets within those files to gather information.

Trouble: vba, using DIR and .open don't understand a file name of it is in Arabic.

Furthermore, once open, vba isn't reading Arabic within cells. So I'm trying to capture the data (written in Arabic) in say, cell A5, but what is saved in the string variable is ?????.

So for both, I'm getting question marks. I read a few other questions here but none answered my issue. I believe this has to do with ANSI and Unicode but I don't know how I can get around this.

Comment: could have a look at the respinse here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78eeab51-f39e-423c-8afc-ebd218d658c3/how-to-make-vba-to-read-and-understand-characters-in-other-keyboard-language?forum=isvvba

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel, in the language settings set the Arabic language as Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
or 
in VB Editor: - 1- click tools 2- Select Options 3- click Editor Format 4- Change font to(Courier New (Arabic)) 5- click OK now you can write in both English and Arabic I hope this will solve your problem